# inner join using mongo query (pymongo)

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to SQL query and first time working with MongoDB using Pymongo.

I have two collections in MongoDB.

```
DEPARTMENT

dept_id   dept_name   status    location     
------------------------------------------
123       sales       active     New York
248       IT          inactive   Vermont
845       HR          active     LA

EMPLOYEE

dept_id   emp_name   emp_salary  emp_status  emp_id
----------------------------------------------------
123       John       25000       active      xyz
845       Mary       90000       active      abc
248       Kevin      50000       inactive    qrs

query 1

select * from DEPARTMENT where dept_id=123 and status='active'

query 2

select emp_name, emp_id from EMPLOYEE where dept_id =123 and status = 'active'
```

i want to inner join these 2 query and return all matching record and give all details from DEPARTMENT table and emp_name, emp_id from EMPLOYEE table.

how will i achieve it using pymongo and sql query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE.emp_name,
    EMPLOYEE.emp_id,
    DEPARTMENT.*
FROM
    EMPLOYEE LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON EMPLOYEE.dept_id = DEPARTMENT.dept_id
WHERE
    EMPLOYEE.dept_id = 123
    AND EMPLOYEE.status = 'active'
    AND DEPARTMENT.status = 'active'
```

Comment: thank you, but most importantly i want it as MongoDB query

Answer (score 0):

```
db.EMPLOYEE.aggregate({ 
$lookup: {
from : "DEPARTMENT", 
localField: "dept_id", 
foreignField: "dept_id",
 as : "EMPLOYEEinDEPARTMENT"}}
,{ $match : { "EMPLOYEEinDEPARTMENT" : { $ne : []}
,"EMPLOYEE.status":{$eq:"active"},"DEPARTMENT.status":{$eq:"active"}
}
})
```

assuming that you have a collection named "EMPLOYEE" and a collection named "DEPARTMENT" in your MongoDB database, and that both collections have a "dept_id" field.

This query uses the $lookup aggregation stage to perform a left outer join between the "EMPLOYEE" collection and the "DEPARTMENT" collection on the "dept_id" fields. The resulting documents will have an "EMPLOYEEinDEPARTMENT" field that contains an array of all matching documents from the "DEPARTMENT" collection.

The query also includes a $match stage that filters the results based on the "status" fields of both the "EMPLOYEE" and "DEPARTMENT" collections. It only returns documents where the "status" is set to "active" for both collections.

Overall, the query appears to be designed to retrieve all employees who belong to an active department.